# Unable to set scope variable within success function of http service

Tags: angularjs

I have a http service where im attempting to save the result to a scope variable, but the debugger keeps returning that the variable does not exist.

Here is the code.

```
...
$scope.valueList = [];
$scope.getValues = function() {
        $http({
            url: '/restservice/values/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: this.json_data,
            headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){
            this.valueList = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Failed"); 
        });
}
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.valueList = data;
```

Should be

```
$scope.valueList = data;
```

Angular is still Javscript, so `this` context scope still apply. Also, `this` in this case does not equal `$scope`.